# Rails Model scopes returning incorrect data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a user model which has a scope attached. Lets call it `foo`

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :foo, ->(thing) { find_by(something: thing) }
end
```

Lets assume that `thing='bar'`

I have one record in the database where `something=baz` so when I do 
`User.foo('bar')`
I should get no results.

However, this returns an `ActiveRecord::Relation` containing the result in the database that does not match.

As you can see, I am using `find_by` so I'm not sure why I am getting a relation back either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're misusing scopes. They need to return relations so that additional scopes can be chained onto them.

It's likely that your `find_by` actually returns `nil`, in which case ActiveRecord ignores the `nil` and returns `all`, so that chaining isn't broken.